# Display records in vertical order in UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I want to display my record in vertical order in a `UITableViewCell`.

Here is my code:

```
cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@ %@",objProp.contid,objProp.contname,objProp.contno];
```

I want to display my record like this.

```
1  

sanjeet

9876556789
```

Comment: Create a custom tableview cell with 3 labels vertically arranged as required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that I would personally tackle this is:

I would create a custom UITableViewCell subclass. I would have three labels in the UITableViewCell, arranged vertically.

```
self.labelA     = [[UILabel alloc] init];
self.labelB     = [[UILabel alloc] init];
self.labelC     = [[UILabel alloc] init];
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = @{@"labelA" : self.labelA,
                                  @"labelB" : self.labelB,
                                  @"labelC" : self.labelC};
[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[labelA]-|"
                                                                         options:kNilOptions
                                                                         metrics:nil
                                                                           views:viewsDictionary]];
[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[labelA]-[labelB]-[labelC]-|"
                                                                         options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeading | NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTrailing
                                                                         metrics:nil
                                                                           views:viewsDictionary]];
```

I would then set each label with the appropriate label.

I believe what you are trying to do is set the textLabel of the default UITableViewCell in such a way where you can introduce new lines. For example:

```
UITableViewCell *tableViewCell;
tableViewCell.textLabel.numberOfLines   = 3;
tableViewCell.textLabel.lineBreakMode   = kNilOptions;
tableViewCell.textLabel.text            = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@\n%@\n%@", variableA, variableB, variableC];
```

Like I said though, the better way would be to create a custom UITableViewCell subclass.

Comment: thanks james below answer is working correctly but NSLineBreakByClipping not working so i removed that line but also it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

u need to create custom `tableviewcell` to display in vertical order. If you are using the storyboard , drag 3 labels in your tableview cell contentview and give different tag to each label and use `[cell viewWithTag:]` method inside your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

example:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];


    UILabel *id = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    id.text = [NSString stringWithFormat=@"%d",objProp.contid];

    UILabel *name = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    name.text = [NSString stringWithFormat=@"%@",objProp.contname];

    UILabel *contact = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
    contact.text = [NSString stringWithFormat=@"%@", objProp.contno];

    return cell;
}
```